# What is the correct way to pass a PHP variable to FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

I just recently started working with FPDF, but I'm still not sure how to pass in my own variables.

I would like to do something like

index.php:

```
...
//set name variable
$name = $_POST["name"]

//embed the pdf
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="my-fpdf.php" type="application/pdf">
....
```

my-fpdf.php:

```
<?php
    require('fpdf.php');

    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $txt = "Hello ".$name."!" //access the variable
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$txt);
    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Is there a best practice on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to add it as a query parameter:

```
<embed ... src="my-fpdf.php?name="<?php echo $name ?>" ...>
```

and then

```
$txt = "Hello, " . $_GET['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable to your PDF Class as such:

```
public $name;
```

Add a function within your PDF Class which accepts a parameter and use this function to set the variable above:

```
public function setName($name){
    $this->name = $name;
}
```

And then you'll be able to access $this->name from within your PDF Class. Don't forget to actually call the function that you just defined (just after the constructor).

```
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->setName('Some Name');
```